# Are these scratches at carbon fiber something to worry?

Tags: carbon

the seller showed me all the scratches at the bike and told that they happened when he was carrying bike and & changing rear wheel all the time. I did not notice any other scratches at the frame. All of these are around rear wheel hub. Are they something to worry? Paint or just structural scratches?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can anyone explain why do so many people insist on carbon the fret over minor cosmetic marks?

Comment: I only see some paint chips caused by inserting the wheel.

Comment: @mattnz for me it’s a combination of informational asymmetry and the theory that carbon can sustain damage in a crash without external signs. That said, I don’t see any reason to think there’s a problem here. Good on the seller for calling out the cosmetic blemishes. I don’t think there’s anything inherently unsafe about carbon; for all the stories some people spread about carbon handlebars, I still prefer them even on my touring bike. I would just be more cautious about a carbon bike on Craigslist, vs finding some paint chips on one that I own or that I might buy from a friend. Just my 2¢